# Open helm search result in a new window?

Tags: helm, window, projectile, window-splitting

Commands like `helm-projectile-grep`, `helm-swoop`, `projectile-find-file` are extremely useful for jumping around code. However, so far I've not found how I can open a search result in a new window (instead, right now pressing `RET` with a search result highlighted opens the search result in the window from which the original search command was executed).

I want to be able to optionally open a search result highlighted in the `*helm grep*` mode either in a horizontally or a vertically tiled window. For instance, I'd like the following functionality:

- Pressing `RET` opens the highlighted result in the current window
- Pressing `C-c h RET` opens the highlighted result in a new, horizontally tiled window
- Pressing `C-c v RET` opens the highlighted result in a new, vertically tiled window

Here's an illustration:

[image]

Is something like this possible? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 8):

`C-z` will bring up a new buffer with actions available to helm, and I see the following:

`[f1] Open file
[f2] Open file other window
[f3] Save results in buffer
[f4] Edit search results`

So you want **`C-z f3`**

After this you can move around the results like a regular buffer, and if you have two windows up, hitting `RET` on a result entry will open the entry in the other window.

**Note** I'm using [spacemacs](http://spacemacs.org/) and [helm-ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), but I assume this will be the same.

Comment: In fact you just need to press `F3`, `C-z` first is not required

Comment: What function do you have associated to `C-z`? I'm on Linux, that makes my Emacs go to sleep (`suspend-frame`)

Comment: @Gauthier Yeah this answer is for `spacemacs`, `TAB` brings up the available actions to helm